# Localhost works after number of refresh WAMp

Tags: wamp

There is a problem on my system as I am using WAMP server. Some time i need to refresh page 2-3 time then it works otherwise it gives "could not connect to server" something like this errors.

I have searched a lot and have checked many thing like SKYPE which is not installed on system IIS is also not installed reinstalled the wamp etc. Is there any other solution for this issue?

Comment: Can you provide log-files or something similarly?

Comment: Latest logs are---           [Tue Jul 02 12:24:56 2013] [notice] Child 8076: Child process is running
[Tue Jul 02 12:24:56 2013] [notice] Child 8076: Acquired the start mutex.
[Tue Jul 02 12:24:56 2013] [notice] Child 8076: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Tue Jul 02 12:24:56 2013] [notice] Child 8076: Starting thread to listen on port 8080.
[Tue Jul 02 12:24:56 2013] [notice] Child 8076: Starting thread to listen on port 8080.
[Tue Jul 02 12:25:01 2013] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.

Comment: Can I ask why you have change the port from 80 to 8080?